# T-SQL: What does this passage in the COALESCE documentation mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> ISNULL and COALESCE though equivalent, can behave differently. An expression involving ISNULL with non-null parameters is considered to be NOT NULL, while expressions involving COALESCE with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its badly worded; its trying to say that IsNull always evaluates as a default Not Null column; whilst Coalesce can evaluate to a default of Null.

```
Create view dbo.pdtest
as

Select  
    ISNULL(GETDATE(), GETDATE()) as test1,
    coalesce(GETDATE(), getdate()) as test2

go

Create view dbo.pdtest2
as

Select  
    ISNULL(GETDATE(), GETDATE()) as test1,
    coalesce(GETDATE(), getdate(), null) as test2
```

When you view the definitions of the columns of the view (in management studio say) the definition on pdTest shows the columns as

```
DateTime not null, 
DateTime not null.
```

On pdtest2 the definition is

```
DateTime Not Null, 
DateTime Null.
```

If you then add a third view; where the isnull statement is evaluated as null

```
Create view dbo.pdtest3
as

Select  
    ISNULL(GETDATE(), null) as test1,
    coalesce(GETDATE(), getdate(), null) as test2
```

The definition of the view data is still Not Null, Null.

Answer (score 5):

It determines the nullability of, say, a computed column using ISNULL or COALESCE

```
RowCheckSum AS COALESCE(...)
```

...means that `RowCheckSum` column definition has `NULL` keyword, and

```
RowCheckSum2 AS ISNULL(...)
```

...has `NOT NULL` definition.

This also means, that in result set first field can return `NULL` values, and second - cannot.

Comment: Please clarify that you mean the definition of the column in the resulting rowset.